# playing fadein/fadeout slider on tab button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have created a Fadein/Fadeout slider. Left button and right button are working fine but I want to play slider by clicking on tab buttons.
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94psxr57/)

HTML

```
    <p id="slide1_controls">
        <div class="block-icon icon-s1">
             <img class="block-img icon-s1" src="../_images/building_icon1.png" data-hover-image="../_images/building_icon1_hover.png" data-selected="false" />
        </div>
        <div class="block-icon icon-s2">
             <img class="block-img icon-s2" src="../_images/building_icon2.png" data-hover-image="../_images/building_icon2_hover.png" data-selected="false" />
        </div>
        <div class="block-icon icon-s3">
             <img class="block-img icon-s3" src="../_images/building_icon3.png" data-hover-image="../_images/building_icon3_hover.png" data-selected="false" />
        </div>
        <div class="block-icon icon-s4">
             <img class="block-img icon-s4" src="../_images/building_icon4.png" data-hover-image="../_images/building_icon4_hover.png" data-selected="false" />
        </div>
    </p>
    <div class="slider-text-context" id="target">
         <div class="slide-01 fade-texts active">tab1</div>
         <div class="slide-02 fade-texts">tab2</div>
         <div class="slide-03 fade-texts">tab3</div>
         <div class="slide-04 fade-texts">tab4</div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .fade-texts {
        width: 100%;
        height: 259px;
        left: 0px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .slider-btn-area {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 8;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        left: 25%;
        top: 54%;
        width: 50%;

    }
    #target > div {
      display:none;   
    }

    #target div:nth-child(1) {
      display:block;   
    }

    .tab-area {
        position: absolute;
        left: 25%;
        top: 30%;
    }
```

Javascript

```
$(".icon-s2").click(function() {
    activeElem = $("#target .slide-02"); 
    activeElem.removeClass('active').fadeOut(0);
    if (!activeElem.is(':first-child')) {
         activeElem.removeClass('active').fadeOut(0).prev().addClass('active').fadeIn(400);
    }
}                        
$(".icon-s3").click(function() {
    activeElem = $("#target .slide-03"); 
    activeElem.removeClass('active').fadeOut(0);
    if (!activeElem.is(':first-child')) {
        activeElem.removeClass('active').fadeOut(0).prev().addClass('active').fadeIn(400);
    }
}
```

When I press the tab it does not work to try to appear a DIV.

Comment: Your fiddle contain syntax errors solve them.

Comment: missing `)` last line

Answer (score 0):

Your code made no sense. The way it looked was that the images had to be clicked in order to `fadeIn/Out` the tabs. I believe it should be the other way. I cleaned up the markup, and simplified the classes, ids, styles, etc...

Here's the **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/1p3xy688/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="slides">
    <div id="slide1" class="slide active">
        <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/150x50/000/Fff.png&text=FIRST" />
    </div>
    <div id="slide2" class="slide">
        <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/150X50/048/Fee.png&text=SECOND" />
    </div>
    <div id="slide3" class="slide">
        <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/150X50/fa8/375.png&text=THIRD" />
    </div>
    <div id="slide4" class="slide">
        <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/150X50/9a7/a10.png&text=FOURTH" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-area" id="controls">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab">1</div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">2</div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab">3</div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab">4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slide {

    display:none;

}

.active {

    display: block;

}

.tab {

    width: 16px;

    height: 16px;

    display: inline-block;

    margin: 0 10px;

    outline: 1px solid black;

    text-align: center;

    cursor: pointer;

}
```

**jQuery/JavaScript**

```
$(function () {

    $('.tab').on('click', function (event) {
        var tabID = event.target.id;
        //console.log('tabID: '+tabID);
        var order = tabID.split('b').pop();
        //console.log('order: '+order);
        var pos = parseInt(order, 10);
        var slideID = 'slide'+pos;
        //console.log('slideID: '+slideID);
        var act = document.getElementById(slideID);
        //console.log('act: '+act.id);
        $('.slide').fadeOut(0).removeClass('active');
        $(act).addClass('active').fadeIn(750);
    });
});
```